# Fix a Custom Menu Link

Tags: wordpress, submenu

I am currently creating a Custom menu and submenu link in wordpress but getting the following error

After saving the menu,

1. the Link URL disappear from the custom menu
2. the Sub menu also shift to become a main menu

Comment: It depends on the WordPress theme and how this theme has the menus defined. What version of WP are you using? What theme? Can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: Actually fixed the issue by repairing the database from the phpMyAdmin. Its working fine now